# Get generic instance generic type using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Given:

```
Type T = typeof(List<string>);
```

Requirement:

```
typeof(List<>) == SomeFunction(T)
```

Many times when I'm reflecting over a type and want to find all properties that return lists of some type...I need the "SomeFunction" shown above. I've searched and searched, but cannot figure out how to  get `List<>` from `List<string>`. I can use T.GetGenericArguments(), but that only returns `string` so that doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
typeof(List<string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
```

Comment: You know, I tried that before, and I saw List`1 and thought that GetGenericTypeDefinition() was returning List<string>. My bad, your solution works great!

Comment: `List\`1` is the same as `List<>`. Likewise, `Func\`2` is `Func<T,R>`.